# Restar porcentaje en tiempo real en un HTML con JavaScript, o llamando a un PHP

Tags: php, javascript, html, angularjs

Es hacer un formulario sencillo donde pongamos el dato de un gasto mensual en numero. la idea es que al hacer `click` en calcular ahorro te muestre abajo nuevamente tu gasto y el ahorro del `8%`. requiero saber si con **AngularJs** o con **php** o **javascript** que un dato que incluya el usuario en un `input` se muestre el resultado abajo con una reducción del 8% del porcentaje.

Es para mi sitio web, una calculadora simple.

Ya con **CSS** le ingresare ese estilo.

Podrían ayudarme?

Adjunto visual del formulario que me piden:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Puede intentar lo siguiente:

```js
function calcular(){
  //Obtienes el valor
  var valor = document.getElementById("valor").value;

  var result= document.getElementById('result');
  var total= document.getElementById('total');

  //le descuentas el 8% y lo agregas al HTML
  var descuento = parseInt(valor)*0.08;

  //agrega los resultados al DOM
  result.innerHTML = 'Ahorro de: $' + descuento;
  total.innerHTML =  'Total:     $' + (parseInt(valor)-descuento);
}
```

```html
Ingrese un valor:
<!--Con el evento "onkeyUp" haces el calculo a medida que ingresan el valor-->
<input id="valor" type="number" onkeyUp="calcular();">
<br>
<br>
<span id="result"></span>
<br>
<span id="total"></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes obtener el valor del input con javascript

```
let gastoInput = document.getElementById('gasto');
let gasto = gastoInput.val();
```

Calculas el ahorro

```
let ahorro = (gasto * 100) / 8;
```

Imprimes el ahorro en HTML con un método como append o innerHTML.

Comment: Dónde está la función val? , además esto no es en tiempo real, ya que el valor del input sería solo una vez captado